# bug when prototype and jQuery are both loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, prototypejs, conflict

I have function in Javascript which works fine using prototype. The function is used to dynamicaly change a select field based on the selection of another field.

```
   var sizes_286 = new Array();
        sizes_286.push(new Array(536, 'Pequeno', 1661));
        sizes_286.push(new Array(536, 'Médio', 1662));
        sizes_286.push(new Array(536, 'Grande', 1663));
        sizes_286.push(new Array(536, 'ExtGrande', 1664));

   function varianteSelected_286(){
      var_id = $('variante_286').getValue();
      options = $('tamanho_286').options;
      options.length = 1;
      sizes_286.each(function(size){
        if (size[0] == var_id){
            options[options.length] = new Option(size[1], size[2]);
        }
    });
}


document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    $('variante_286').observe('change', varianteSelected_286);
});
```

The problem is that I started to use jQuery in my project, and since then this function stopped working. I'm using jQuery (1.3.2) and prototype (1.6.1).

- How can I create a jquery version of my old function? or
- How can I make it still work after jquery is being loaded?
- Is there a short and more elegant version of the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I was you I would try to avoid using both frameworks. Just do it in jQuery, like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sizes_286 = [
        {id: 536, name: 'Pequeno', size: 1661},
        {id: 536, name: 'Médio', size: 1662},
        {id: 536, name: 'Grande', size: 1663},
        {id: 536, name: 'ExtGrande', size: 1664}
    ];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#variante_286').change(function(){
            var var_id = $(this).val();
            var select = $('#tamanho_286');

            var options = '';
            $.each(sizes_286, function(i, n){
                if (n.id == var_id) {
                    options += '<option value="' + n.size + '">' + n.name + '</option>';
                }
            });

            select.html(options);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your implementation worked well for me and now I've disabled prototype. Thaks!

Comment: No worries, but actually I missed double brackets in my code, should be '<option value="' + n.size + '">, I edited my post to include them. Code will work correctly even without them, but to make HTML valid we should put them in.

Comment: I've tested this code in IE8 and it is not working! Any suggestion?

Comment: I've found the error in IE8: inside the each function, I have to verify if n is defined, don't know why:

        if (typeof(n) != "undefined"){
                      if (n.id == var_id) {
                              options += '<option value="' + n.size + '">' + n.name + '</option>';
            }
}

Comment: Are you using standard IE8 or IE8 in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 5):

There are sometimes problem with the $ function of Jquery with the same from protoype and in such cases we call a function so that Jquery $ function does not clash with that of Prototype.

The function is jquery.noConflict()

Please refer to the link :
http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 2):

Beginner is right about how to get jquery and prototype to run together, but if that's all you need it for, i think you're better off re-writing your function to jquery, and get rid of the need to run both frameworks parallel. The following should work (leave the array declaration as it is):

```
function varianteSelected_286() {
  var_id = $(this).val();
  options = $('#tamanho_286')[0].options;
  options.length = 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < sizes_286.length; i++) {
     var size = sizes_286[i];
     if (size[0] == var_id) {
        options[options.length] = new Option(size[1], size[2]);
     }
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#variante_286').change(varianteSelected_286);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function scope to use jQuery as `$` and you could probably leave Prototype as the default `$`.

jQuery code:

```
(function($) {
    $('body').hide()
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```